# Get the Post meta wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

If

```
<?php the_title(); ?> = ' . get_the_title() . '
<?php the_permalink(); ?> = ' . get_permalink() . '
```

then,

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'staff_photo', true); ?> = ?
```

I need it in a custom query.

Comment: note: staff_photo is my custom field key.

Comment: What do you mean you need it in a custom query?

Comment: I mean query post. I will query custom post. 

like this: http://web-design-weekly.com/blog/snippets/recent-post-shortcode/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **get_the_ID()** to get the ID of your post in the loop, and use that ID to get the post meta.

```
function my_recent_posts_shortcode($atts){
    $q = new WP_Query(
        array( 'orderby' => 'date', 'posts_per_page' => '4', 'post_type' => 'events')
        );
$list = '<ul class="recent-posts">';
while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    //get the ID of your post in the loop
    $id = get_the_ID();
    //now get your registration link
    $link = get_post_meta($id, 'registration_link', true);        
    $list .= '<li>' . get_the_date() . '<a href="' . $link . '">Register</a><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>' . '<br />' . get_the_excerpt() . '</ul>';        
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
return $list;
}
add_shortcode('recent-posts', 'my_recent_posts_shortcode');
```

Comment: It is working for post. How can I make this for custom post? 

like

'post_type' => 'events'

Comment: Change your WP_Query arguments to `array('orderby' => 'date', 'post_type' => 'events', 'posts_per_page' => 4)`

Comment: Updated the answer to get events post type.

Comment: When I change WP_Query to post_type events, I can't see the custom field data. Getting title, date & excerpt.

Comment: Have you enabled custom post meta for your events custom post type?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled by functions.php

'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'custom-fields' )

Comment: Ok. Then did you save anything in your custom fields for the name `staff_photo` and it has a value? If you did, it should work. Can you update your question by pasting your actual code?

Comment: Yes, I saved value for that custom field. Also added same value in post for text. 

When I add that query for post, the custom field data is showing. But, when I add post_type events, the custom field data is not showing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39194/discussion-between-rasel-ahmed-and-webnovice)

Answer (score 0):

Try print_r($customFields) or print_r($post), these array probebly have the data U need.
Don't forget to declare them as global first.